# Determine the corners coordinate in Google maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How could I determine the visible map corner coordinate:[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`getBounds()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) method of your map, which returns a [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object.

> Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the result is null or undefined.

[Maps V3 Javascript API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)